# Creating a new user role with Drush

Tags: drush

I can do loads of user-related stuff with Drush, but I can't see how to create new user roles. Is it possible to do this with Drush?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This functionality is available in Drush 8.x-6.x:

```
 role-add-perm (rap)   Grant a specified permission to a role.                  
 role-create (rcrt)    Create a new role.                                       
 role-delete (rdel)    Delete a role.                                           
 role-list (rls)       Display a list of all roles defined on the system.  If a 
                       role name is provided as an argument, then all of the    
                       permissions of that role will be listed.  If a           
                       permission name is provided as an option, then all of    
                       the roles that have been granted that permission will be 
                       listed.                                                  
 role-remove-perm      Remove a specified permission from a role.               
 (rmp)
```

Unfortunately, this has not been backported to the 7.x-5.x branch, so it probably won't be in the soon-to-be-released Drush-5.9, and isn't in Drush-5.8.  For now, you'll have to use the dev branch to get it.

Answer (score 4):

To get a list of all drush based commands just type `drush` at the command prompt and it will list all the set of commands available.

`drush help [command]` to view command-specific help.

Run `drush topic` to read even more documentation.

**Drush user specific commands**

> User commands: (user)
>
> user-add-role (urol)  Add a role to the specified user accounts.
>
> user-block (ublk)     Block the specified user(s).
>
> user-cancel (ucan)    Cancel a user account with the specified name.
>
> user-create (ucrt)    Create a user account with the specified name.
>
> user-information      Print information about the specified user(s). 
>   (uinf)
>
> user-login (uli)      Display a one time login link for the given
>   user account (defaults to uid 1).
>
> user-password (upwd)  (Re)Set the password for the user account with
>   the specified name.
>
> user-remove-role      Remove a role from the specified user accounts.
>   (urrol)
>
> user-unblock (uublk)  Unblock the specified user(s).

Comment: Can you add in the syntax that generate this?

Comment: drush help --filter=user

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Drush script I made to use with Drush 5.9. Just name as `user_roles.drush.inc` under `~/.drush` and then `drush cc drush`.

```
<?php
// user_roles.drush.inc
// author: yuvals

function user_roles_drush_command() {
        $items = array();

        $items['roles-delete'] = array(
                'description' => 'Delete one or more user roles.',
                'arguments' => array(
                        'ids' => 'Comma delimited list of user role IDs (rid).',
                ),
                'examples' => array(
                        'drush roles-delete 30,31,32' => 'Deletes the specified user roles.',
                        'drush roles-delete' => 'Prompts for selection of user roles to delete.',
                ),
                'bootstrap' => DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_DRUPAL_FULL,
        );

        $items['roles-list'] = array(
                'description' => 'Lists user roles.',
                'bootstrap' => DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_DRUPAL_FULL,
        );

        return $items;
}

function drush_user_roles_roles_list() {
        foreach (user_roles() as $rid=>$name) {
                        drush_print(sprintf("%-7d\t%s", $rid, $name));
        }
}

function drush_user_roles_roles_delete($ids = NULL) {

        $roles = user_roles();

        if ($ids == NULL) {
                $options = array();
                foreach ($roles as $rid=>$name) {
                        // keys must be string otherwise array_merge inside drush_choice_multiple overwrites them
                        $options['.'.$rid] = $name;
                }
                $selection = drush_choice_multiple($options, FALSE, 'Choose which user roles you would like to delete.', '!value');
                if ($selection == null) {
                        return;
                }
                $ids = array();
                foreach ($selection as $id_string) {
                        $ids[] = intval(substr($id_string, 1)); // hack - remove '.' prefix; see above
                }
        }
        else {
                $valid_ids = array();
                $ids = explode(',', $ids);
                foreach ($ids as $id) {
                        $id = intval($id);
                        if (isset($roles[$id])) {
                                $valid_ids[] = $id;
                        }
                }
                $ids = $valid_ids;
        }

        if (count($ids) == 0) {
                return drush_log(dt('No user roles to delete.'));
        }
        $message = dt("The following @number user roles will be deleted:\n", array('@number' => count($ids)));
        $role_table = sprintf("%-7s%s\n", dt('rid'), dt('name'));
        foreach ($ids as $id) {
                $role_table .= sprintf("%-7d%s\n", $id, $roles[$id]);
        }
        $role_table = sprintf("%-7s%s\n", dt('rid'), dt('name'));
        foreach ($ids as $id) {
                $role_table .= sprintf("%-7d%s\n", $id, $roles[$id]);
        }
        $message .= $role_table;

        if (drush_confirm($message)) {
                foreach ($ids as $rid) {
                        user_role_delete($rid);
                }
                drush_log(dt("@number user roles were deleted:\n@role_table", array('@number' => count($ids), '@role_table' => $role_table)));
        }

}
```