# How to manage user permissions?

Tags: drush

I would like to manage user permissions with Drush, but I don't find any command on the official documentation website.

How to achieve this?

I am using Drupal 6, and Drush 6.0-dev.

Comment: Drush is not supposed to do that. Its a site builder/developer tool.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this command:

```
drush role-add-perm 'user-role' 'permission'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can install the [Permissions API](http://drupal.org/project/permissions_api)

> The permissions_api module provides a method for granting and revoking
>   permissions for a given role. This module helps with the issue of
>   staging a Drupal site across multiple environments, from development
>   sandbox to production environment.

...

> Version 6.x-2.9 adds support for **Drush**!

Comment: ok i install the api permissions module, then where can i found commands ? i don't know how to see help in drush..

Answer (score 2):

permissions_api will work for your purposes, but as of yet it has no 7.x version.  For those who want a solution that works with both Drupal 6 and Drupal 7, Drush v6.0-dev has commands to manage roles and permissions built in.  See `drush help` and this previous answer: [Creating a new user role with Drush](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/56451/creating-a-new-user-role-with-drush/56457#56457)

Regarding finding the commands available in a module that has Drush support, use `drush help --filter`, and Drush will show the available command groupings. Select the module you are interested in, and all of the Drush commands it supports will be displayed.  If you are having trouble getting Drush to recognize a new commandfile, try `drush cc drush` to clear the Drush command cache.  Drush will do this automatically when a new module is downloaded and enabled, but you may need to do it manually if you copy in a Drush commandfile by hand.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried ?

```
 drush php-eval 'node_access_rebuild();'
```

Comment: no,but i will when need appear